# Counting words in column and then display said amount on userform

Tags: vba, excel, report, userform

I don't know if this is possible or if I'm just searching wrong keywords.

Basically I have user-form with multi-page arrangement and I wondered if it possible for one of multi-pages to display running tally of what on the worksheet.

Example:on spreadsheet (Data) column B description of asset: Laptop, Desktop, Printer etc. and then User-form looks at sheet (Data) and then display to end user on user-form running tally of Laptops = 7 Desktop = 9 Printers = 2.

Depending on how many words are in that column matching the word looking for.

I don't know where to start to create code to do is and I can't seem to find any help on any websites when searching Google (VBA User-form to display column count).

Sorry If I'm not asking in correct way on here just at complete loss with what to do.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That's okay if you really don't know where to start, but you must give us something which helps us to recreate your situation. Otherwise the solutions will vary wildly. As a bare minimum, edit your question to include some sample data and perhaps a screenshot of what your userform looks like.

Comment: Why have you never replied to these answers?

Comment: At the time I told to move onto other functions the user form could do after looking at these answers not sure that what I was after. looking for user form to show live stats of how many matching words were in a column. I'll look into it again now.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function to do this.

Assign all the cells in your column into a string, then push that string into your function.

```
Function countWords(ByVal sText As String) As Long

    Dim sTextArr() As String
    sTextArr = Split(sText, " ")
    countWords = UBound(sTextArr) + 1

End Function

Sub test()

    Dim myStr As String
    myStr = "The dog barked non-stop. I wish he would stop"
    MsgBox countWords(myStr)

End Sub
```

You would just assign the value of `countWords` to your userform control.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the values into a ListBox with two columns on your UserForm, having the item in the first column and the count of items in the second column then the following will help:

```
Sub foo()
Dim k As Variant
Dim d As Variant
Dim c As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column B
Set rng = ws.Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For Each c In rng
    d(c.Value) = d(c.Value) + 1
Next c

For Each k In d
    If k <> "" Then
        ListBox1.AddItem k
        ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 1) = d(k)
    End If
Next k
End Sub
```